# Unable to assgin int value to ORA_JAVA.JOBJECT while calling java class files from plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a Java stub which I'm trying to call from PL/SQL, my all the method having Input parameters as Int Data type in Java code after I imported Java code into Oracle forms, and all the procedure and function after import are having Data type of ORA_JAVA.JOBJECT.

Can someone help me to assign int value for ORA_JAVA.JOBJECT variable? 
Tried assigning using Int_array :

```
DECLARE
    jo ora_java.jobject;
    a0 ora_java.jobject; 
    xo ora_java.jobject; 
    ex ora_java.jobject;
    a number;
BEGIN 
    JO := EmployeeInfoService.new;   
    a0 := EmployeeInfoService.new;   

    a0 := ORA_JAVA.NEW_INT_ARRAY(1);    
    ORA_JAVA.SET_INT_ARRAY_ELEMENT(a0, 0, 10001);   
    xo := employeeInfoServicePortType.getEmpInfoById(JO,a0, a0);
EXCEPTION
        WHEN ORA_JAVA.JAVA_ERROR then 
            MESSAGE ('Unable to call out to Java, ' ||ORA_JAVA.LAST_ERROR);
        WHEN ORA_JAVA.EXCEPTION_THROWN then
            ex := ORA_JAVA.LAST_EXCEPTION;  
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            MESSAGE('Error : ' || sqlerrm);`enter code here`
END;
```

upon execution of this ending of with error: Invalid object type for argument 1.

upon successful execution of this, I should get xo with employee information.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you could see that a0 was first set to `EmployeeInfoService.new`, and then to an array; effectively overwriting the previous line.

Also, you need to see exactly what type of object the procedure is `employeeInfoServicePortType.getEmpInfoById` is expecting. In the generated code for `getEmpInfoById`, you may see one of the lines below:

1. `JNI.ADD_OBJECT_ARG(args, a0);`
2. `JNI.ADD_OBJECT_ARG(args, a0, 'java/lang/Integer');`

If it looks like #1, then passing in a value like 10001 is fine.

If it looks like #2, you would have to import the `java.lang.Integer` object into your form and pass in the value like `Integer.new(10001)`.

Oracle Forms can convert `String` to a `VARCHAR2`, and `int` to `NUMBER`, but everything else would be set to ORA_JAVA.JOBJECT.

The following java method declarations show the difference in what code would be generated in Oracle Forms:

```
  public getEmpInfoById(int arg0, int arg1)... this would generate #1
  public getEmpInfoById(Integer arg0, Integer arg1)... this would generate #2
```

I suspect in your case it is the latter. If you have access to the Java code, try and change it to use int instead of Integer. If this isn't possible, import the java.lang.Integer object into your form/library. And then use as follows:

```
PROCEDURE test IS
    lo_integer ORA_JAVA.JOBJECT;
BEGIN
    lo_integer := Integer.new(10001);
    -- rest of the code
END;
```

Here's a couple of links with more info on the Java Importer:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/javaimporter-130505.pdf
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a86202/appc.htm